# EmberJS - How to establish hasMany relationship on same attribute

Tags: ember.js

I have the below sample JSONAPI. I want to load it in ember data.

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "in",
    "type": "product-offering",
    "relationships": {
      "products": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "group-product",
            "id": "group-product-001"
          },
          {
            "type": "sub-product",
            "id": "sub-product-001"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Can any one please let me know how can I have the relationship in product-offering model?

I want something like that..

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  products: hasMany('group-product'),
  products: hasMany('sub-product')
});
```

How can I use the hasmany relationship on same attribute for 2 models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use a polymorphic relationship.
So you need a common base type:

**models/base-product.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
});
```

And then your sub-models:

**models/group-product.js**

```
import BaseProduct is './base-product';
export default BaseProduct.extend({
});
```

**models/sub-product.js**

```
import BaseProduct is './base-product';
export default BaseProduct.extend({
});
```

With that you can define a polymorphic relationship on your `product-offering`:

**models/product-offering.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
  products: DS.hasMany('base-product'),
});
```